# Dynamically adding menu item won't toggle in sidebar-nav to Sb Admin 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and JQuery. I am having a problem with SB Admin 2 bootstrap. I've stripped down an example (Dashboard) page and added a menu item to the sidebar-nav dynamically.

The problem is that the new menu item won't toggle / collapse.

Below is a snippet of the html of side menu which works.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbar_brand">SB Admin v2.0</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-header -->

    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                <li>
        <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
        </li>
        <!-- /.dropdown -->
    </ul>
    <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
</nav>
```

To dynamically add a new menu item I've added a click event handler as below.

```
$("#navbar_brand").click(function(){
    $("#side-menu").append('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> TEST Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a><ul class="nav nav-second-level"><li><a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a></li><li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li></ul></li>');
});
```

The new menu item appears but doesn't toggle as the original Samples Pages menu. Could somebody help?

TIA

*** UPDATE ***

Please find below html file in question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbar_brand">SB Admin v2.0</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Hover Rows
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>First Name</th>
                                            <th>Last Name</th>
                                            <th>Username</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>Mark</td>
                                            <td>Otto</td>
                                            <td>@mdo</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>Jacob</td>
                                            <td>Thornton</td>
                                            <td>@fat</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>Larry</td>
                                            <td>the Bird</td>
                                            <td>@twitter</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->


    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/core/js/common.js"></script>    

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Page Custom JavaScript code -->
    <script>

    $( window ).on('load', function() {
        console_log("page loadedd");

        $(window).ready(function(){
            console_log("page ready");

            // setup page
            $.pageInit();
        });     
    });

    $.pageInit = function() {

    }

    $("#navbar_brand").click(function(){
        console_log("test");

        $("#side-menu").append('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> TEST Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a><ul class="nav nav-second-level"><li><a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a></li><li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li></ul></li>');


    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I see the code where you're initiating the `sidebar-nav` functionality? I believe it's recognizing the `<li>`s that exist in the HTML when the JavaScript is first read. However, when you dynamically add a new `<li>` at a later time, the toggle functionality hasn't been added, since it was created after.

Comment: I have update the original post above with the code as required.

Comment: A colleague pointed out the solution today. Add the following after appending menu items $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what the `#side-menu` functionality is without being able to look inside the JS scripts you're using, but you need to pay attention to the order in which JavaScript works. This is what your browser is doing:

1. Reading the HTML document.
2. Loading and executing all .js files. In here, your plugin is looking for `#side-menu` and applying functionality to its 2 existing `<li>` child elements.
3. Upon clicking on `#navbar_brand`, it's adding a 3rd `<li>` child to `#side-menu`, but this one never has any functionality added to it, since that took place in step 2.

You have 2 options:

1. Look into the plugin's features, and see if you can initiate it again **after** you've added the 3rd `<li>` child.
2. Have all 3 `<li>`s built into the HTML document, but have `display: none` in the CSS for the 3rd one. Once you click on `#navbar_brand` you can show it by changing its style to `display: block` or whatever you wish.

Comment: Make sense what you have stated. Ill be looking into trying to initiate the plugin again after the 3rd child is added. I have added the link for the git repo which includes the js scripts. https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2

Comment: Thanks Marco, ill be frantically looking for a solution. If anyone can point me in the right direction with regards to re-initiate plugins (even better with sb admin 2 bootstrap) id be most grateful :)